# DropboxAuthError: Error getting request token. Is your app key and secret correctly set? Server returned 400: Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

rake aborted!
DropboxAuthError: Error getting request token. Is your app key and secret correctly set? Server returned 400: Bad Request.

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:277:in get_token'

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:293:inget_request_token'

/home/tesr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/dropbox-sdk-1.6.5/lib/dropbox_sdk.rb:299:in get_authorize_url'

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/paperclip-dropbox-1.3.2/lib/paperclip/dropbox/rake.rb:11:inauthorize'

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/paperclip-dropbox-1.3.2/lib/paperclip/dropbox/tasks.rake:11:in block (2 levels) in '

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in'

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'

/home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in'

Tasks: TOP => dropbox:authorize

Comment: Please help me . Give me any idea.

Comment: There is some config issue like dropbox_access_token not match.and i'm solve this issue create file dropbox.rb and put code.

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.dropbox_access_token = cnkzo6ewuCiVgNGkZ1cJJUjgrsvyX4IB"
end